# Send attachment with Laravel SMTP and save to local storage

Tags: laravel, email, smtp, attachment

I read a similar topic in the forum solved, but it did not work successfully in me. Where am I making a mistake?

View

```
<input type="file" class="" name="document">
```

Send

```
Mail::send([], [], function ($message) use ($request) {
$message->to($request->to);
$message->subject($request->subject);
$message->setBody($request->message);
$data = $request->document;
$message->attach($data['document']->getRealPath(), array(
'as' => $data['document']->getClientOriginalName(),
'mime' => $data['document']->getMimeType()));
```

I want to send the attachment in this way, but it does not. Do I need to upload and then send it first?

Comment: Could you please post an error you are getting? I think that by reading it carefully, you might actually come up with partial solution ;)

Comment: I get it from the input part as request-> documents. $ data = request-> documents.

Comment: Call to a member function getRealPath () on null
getRealPath () and getClientOriginalName () cannot find them.
I think the $ data array is empty.

Answer (score 0):

There is a whole section about files in requests at official laravel's docs.

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/requests#files

https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Http/UploadedFile.html

So, according to the above docs, the file you upload is (temporarly) saved when processing the request - you do not need to save it yourself.

```
$document_path = $request->document->path();   

$message->attach($document_path, array(
    'as' => $request->document->getClientOriginalName(),
    'mime' => $request->document->getMimeType())
);
```

Comment: dd ($ request-> document);
Its output is not found on this empty road () like the city.
Symfony \ Component \ HttpFoundation \ FileBag {# 55 ▼
#parameters: []
}

Comment: Are you sure that you are sending the file on the browser-side correctly?

Comment: Yes, I send it in the form with the post method.
Subject, to whom etc. are working, attachement sounds empty.

Comment: use Illuminate \ Support \ Facades \ File;
it didn't work because I wasn't using it. The cause of the error is import. But I can't still send multicast. This is my foreach loop.
$ files = $ request-> file ('attachment');
foreach ($ files as $ file) {
     $ Message-> attach ($ file-> getrealpath () [
         'as' => $ file-> getClientOriginalName ()
     ]);
}